# Xamarin Forms - Set BindingContext of a controltemplate

Tags: mvvm, xamarin.forms, data-binding, controltemplate

I have a xamarin forms application. It has a tabbedpage within it multiple tabs. The tabbedpage and te tabs, each of them has their own viewmodel as a bindingcontext.

In the app.xaml I defined a controltemplate. I use this control template in each tab, because I want each of those tabs to have a button at the bottom of the page.

At this moment: the button in the controltemplate binds with a property defined in each tab. But I want the button to bind at one place. Isn't it possible to create a viewmodel special for the controltemplate and bind the button defined in the controltemplate with that viewmodel?

Current code:

```
        <ControlTemplate x:Key="ActivityStatusButton">
            <StackLayout>

                <ContentPresenter>

                </ContentPresenter>

                <StackLayout VerticalOptions="EndAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="Fill" Padding="15">

                    <Button Style="{StaticResource RedBackGroundWithWhiteTextButtonStyle}" Command="{TemplateBinding BindingContext.ClickOnStatusButton, Mode=TwoWay}" Text="{TemplateBinding BindingContext.ok, Mode=TwoWay}"></Button>
                </StackLayout>

            </StackLayout>
        </ControlTemplate>
```

A typical tab:

```
<ContentPage ...>

<ContentPage.Content>
    <Label Text="hello"></Label>
</ContentPage.Content>

<!--The control template is placed here (the button) -->
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create a Custom Control (a subclass of ContentView) like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ContentView xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" 
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:d="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms/design"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
             mc:Ignorable="d"

             x:Name="template"

             x:Class="App24.MyControlTemplate">
  <ContentView.Content>


        <StackLayout VerticalOptions="EndAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="Fill" Padding="15">

            <Button Clicked="Button_Clicked" Command="{Binding Source={x:Reference template},Path=ButtonCommand}" Text="{Binding  Source={x:Reference template},Path=ButtonText}" CommandParameter="{Binding  Source={x:Reference template},Path=CommandParameter}" />
        </StackLayout>

    </ContentView.Content>
</ContentView>
```

```
using System;

using System.Windows.Input;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Xaml;

namespace App24
{
    [XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
    public partial class MyControlTemplate : ContentView
    {
        public event EventHandler ButtonClick;

        public static readonly BindableProperty ButtonTextProperty =
        BindableProperty.Create("ButtonText", typeof(string), typeof(MyControlTemplate), default(string));

        public string ButtonText
        {
            get => ((string)GetValue(ButtonTextProperty));
            set => SetValue(ButtonTextProperty, value);
        }

        public static readonly BindableProperty ButtonCommandProperty =
        BindableProperty.Create("ButtonCommand", typeof(ICommand), typeof(MyControlTemplate), null, BindingMode.Default, null);


        public ICommand ButtonCommand
        {
            get => (ICommand)GetValue(ButtonCommandProperty);
            set
            {
                SetValue(ButtonCommandProperty, value);

            }
        }

        public static readonly BindableProperty CommandParameterProperty =
            BindableProperty.Create("CommandParameter", typeof(object), typeof(MyControlTemplate), null);

        public object CommandParameter
        {
            get => (object)GetValue(CommandParameterProperty);
            set => SetValue(CommandParameterProperty, value);
        }

        public MyControlTemplate()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

        }



        private void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ButtonClick?.Invoke(sender, e);
        }
    }
}
```

Now you could add it to any page and binding **Text** , **Command** or **CommandParameter** in code behind .

```
<StackLayout VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand">

        <local:MyControlTemplate   ButtonText="{Binding ButtonText}" ButtonCommand="{Binding ClickCommand}" CommandParameter="test" />

</StackLayout>
```

Comment: Looks good, but can't I achieve this with control templates? Because I have a feeling custom controls is better used in this usecase.

Comment: In that way you need to binding the property in each viewmodel .

Comment: In addition , use custom view is more friendly if your project is based on MVVM :)